# How can I replace the first blank space followed by a capital letter with a line break?

Tags: replace, notepad++

So I have this text (it has more than a thousand lines):

```
ABO blood group antigens Carbohydrate antigens attached mainly to cell surface proteins or lipids that are present on many cell types, including red blood cells. These antigens differ among individuals, depending on inherited alleles encoding the enzymes required for synthesis of the carbohydrate antigens. The ABO antigens act as alloantigens that are responsible for blood transfusion reactions and hyperacute rejection of allografts.

Acquired immunodeficiency A deficiency in the immune system that is acquired after birth, usually because of infection (e.g., AIDS), and that is not related to a genetic defect. Synonymous with secondary immunodeficiency.

Acquired immunodeficiency syndrome (AIDS) A disease caused by human immunodeficiency virus (HIV) infection that is characterized by depletion of CD4+ T cells, leading to a profound defect in cell-mediated immunity. Clinically, AIDS includes opportunistic infections, malignant tumors, wasting, and encephalopathy.

Activation-induced cell death (AICD) Apoptosis of activated lymphocytes, generally used for T cells.

Activation-induced (cytidine) deaminase (AID) An enzyme expressed in B cells that catalyzes the conversion of cytosine into uracil in DNA, which is a step required for somatic hypermutation and affinity maturation of antibodies and for Ig class switching.

Activation protein 1 (AP-1) A family of DNA-binding transcription factors composed of dimers of two proteins that bind to one another through a shared structural motif called a leucine zipper. The best-characterized AP-1 factor is composed of the proteins Fos and Jun. AP-1 is involved in transcriptional regulation of many different genes that are important in the immune system, such as cytokine genes.
```

And I'd like it to be like this:

```
ABO blood group antigens
Carbohydrate antigens attached mainly to cell surface proteins or lipids that are present on many cell types, including red blood cells. These antigens differ among individuals, depending on inherited alleles encoding the enzymes required for synthesis of the carbohydrate antigens. The ABO antigens act as alloantigens that are responsible for blood transfusion reactions and hyperacute rejection of allografts.

Acquired immunodeficiency
A deficiency in the immune system that is acquired after birth, usually because of infection (e.g., AIDS), and that is not related to a genetic defect. Synonymous with secondary immunodeficiency.

Acquired immunodeficiency syndrome (AIDS)
A disease caused by human immunodeficiency virus (HIV) infection that is characterized by depletion of CD4+ T cells, leading to a profound defect in cell-mediated immunity. Clinically, AIDS includes opportunistic infections, malignant tumors, wasting, and encephalopathy.

Activation-induced cell death (AICD)
Apoptosis of activated lymphocytes, generally used for T cells.

Activation-induced (cytidine) deaminase (AID)
An enzyme expressed in B cells that catalyzes the conversion of cytosine into uracil in DNA, which is a step required for somatic hypermutation and affinity maturation of antibodies and for Ig class switching.

Activation protein 1 (AP-1)
A family of DNA-binding transcription factors composed of dimers of two proteins that bind to one another through a shared structural motif called a leucine zipper. The best-characterized AP-1 factor is composed of the proteins Fos and Jun. AP-1 is involved in transcriptional regulation of many different genes that are important in the immune system, such as cytokine genes.
```

Is there a way around it? I'm not a programmer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your text locally and this worked, I'm not a regex expert so it may not be the most efficient.

Using the 'Replace' tab (`Ctrl+H`):

Find what: `^(.*?) ([A-Z].*$)`
Replace with: `\1\r\n\2`

Make sure **Match case** and **Regular expression** are checked.

*Explanation*:
Find what:

```
^           starts with
.           anything
*           repeated 0 or more times
?           lazy match so that it stops at the capital letter (next group)
(.*?)       remember that part (group 1)
            followed by a space
[A-Z]       match the capital letter
.           anything
*           repeated 0 or more times
$           ends with
([A-Z].*$)  remember that part (group 2)
```

Replace with

```
\1          group 1
\r          carriage return
\n          new line
\2          group 2
```

Comment: I have no idea of what you did there but it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a replace using [regular expressions](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) (looking for a space followed by a capital letter).

In notepad++ use find/replace with regular expressions (be sure to check "Match Case")

find what: ([^.]) ([A-Z])
replace with: \1\r\n\2

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Use a perl script. This one works me thinks...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$cestbon = 0;
while (<>) {
@line = split(" ",$_);
if (/^$/) {
            $cestbon = 0;
    print "\n";
    }
foreach (@line) {
    if (/\b[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\b/ && $cestbon < 2) {
      print "\n$_ ";
      $cestbon++;
    } else {
      print "$_ ";
    }
}
}
```

To run it! cause this is on a MBP, running OS X aka UNIX.

cat sample.txt | ./sample.pl

```
ABO blood group antigens 
Carbohydrate antigens attached mainly to cell surface proteins or lipids that are present on many cell types, including red blood cells. 
These antigens differ among individuals, depending on inherited alleles encoding the enzymes required for synthesis of the carbohydrate antigens. The ABO antigens act as alloantigens that are responsible for blood transfusion reactions and hyperacute rejection of allografts. 

Acquired immunodeficiency 
A deficiency in the immune system that is acquired after birth, usually because of infection (e.g., AIDS), and that is not related to a genetic defect. Synonymous with secondary immunodeficiency. 

Acquired immunodeficiency syndrome (AIDS) 
A disease caused by human immunodeficiency virus (HIV) infection that is characterized by depletion of CD4+ T cells, leading to a profound defect in cell-mediated immunity. Clinically, AIDS includes opportunistic infections, malignant tumors, wasting, and encephalopathy. 

Activation-induced cell death (AICD) 
Apoptosis of activated lymphocytes, generally used for T cells. 

Activation-induced (cytidine) deaminase (AID) 
An enzyme expressed in B cells that catalyzes the conversion of cytosine into uracil in DNA, which is a step required for somatic hypermutation and affinity maturation of antibodies and for Ig class switching. 

Activation protein 1 (AP-1) 
A family of DNA-binding transcription factors composed of dimers of two proteins that bind to one another through a shared structural motif called a leucine zipper. The best-characterized AP-1 factor is composed of the proteins Fos and Jun. AP-1 is involved in transcriptional regulation of many different genes that are important in the immune system, such as cytokine genes.
```

may not be perfect, but I wrote it in 10 minutes, so give me break :)